# Compare two windows folders for differences and post them out to a new folder(Beyond compare)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

I have the following scenario

```
Folder 1
 -Folder a
      -File1.txt
      -Img1.png
 -Folder b
      -File2.txt
      -Img2.png

Folder 2
 -Folder a
      -File1.txt (File 1 modified)
      -Img1.png   (No change)
 -Folder b
      -File3.txt (New file added)
      -Img2.png  (no change)
```

Basically I want the output folder to have the following files(modified or added in the original structure, with the structure preserved)

```
OutputFolder
  -Folder a
       -File1.txt
  -Folder b 
       -File3.txt
```

I am trying to use the Beyond Compare Command line to do this, but I cant find any arguments to suit and I dont want to loop over all files(too many files) for changes manually or use SVN. Any other tool/script I could use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the changes are only in the "Folder 2"-Structure and Folder 1 will always be untuched, i got it to work with:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,* DELIMS=  " %%A IN ('ROBOCOPY "Folder 2" "Folder 1" /MIR /XX /NDL /NJH /NJS /L') DO (
  SET tmpFolder=%%~dpB
  SET tmpFolder=!tmpFolder:Folder 2=OutputFolder!
  XCOPY "%%~B" "!tmpFolder!" /E /F /H /R /C
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Robocopy will only list the changes between folder 2 and folder 1, 
the for loop will copy the files to the "outputfolder", keeping the folder-structure

Comment: Thanks! Yes assumption about folders is right, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Any (Error) Message? 
How's your original Folderstructure?

Comment: Ahhh... hahaha... i forgot to remove the `/L`-Param from `XCOPY`. So `XCOPY` will atm only list, but not copy xD Sorry. I removed it from the original-post.

Comment: Still no (error)-message or your originalfolderstructure... how's your exact code?

Comment: Nope, same folder structure as above, ill debug with messages and get back! Thanks!

Comment: Does not seem to be going into the for loop at all, have all the folder structures correct. It just skips over. If I do only robocpy line on cmd, it prints the differences

Comment: Please add "LOG:Robocopylog" after the /NJH /NJS /L-Switch: `/NJH /NJS /L /LOG:Robocopy.log`

Comment: It prints correctly - the log -  `Newer              9 C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Folder2\A\1.txt
     New File           0 C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Folder2\B\4.txt`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64762/discussion-between-slartibartfast-and-baba).

Comment: so there's no space between "folder" and "2". Have you changed the code to fit that? Are you sure, that the char after "delims=" is a tab-Character?